# Temperature dependent heat capacity and entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

this problem is often presented as a simple demonstration of relationship between the heat capacity at constant volume $C_V$ and entropy $S$.

Let's say the heat capacity $C_V$ is equal to $a T + b T^3$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. We then have
$$
\mathrm{d} S = \frac{C_V (T)}{T} \mathrm{d} T \quad \implies \quad S (T) = a T + \frac{b}{3} T^3
$$

However, this got me thinking: we know, that strictly speaking, entropy is a two-variable function, so, for example,
$$
\mathrm{d} S = \frac{C_V}{T} \mathrm{d} T + \frac{\alpha}{\beta_T} \mathrm{d} V
$$
so even if *none* of the constants depend on volume and only $C_V$ depends on temperature, entropy will have a volume-dependent "constant" (with respect to temperature) term.

Alternatively if we express $\mathrm{d} S$ via $\mathrm{d} T$ and $\mathrm{d} p$ (both this and previous relations for $\mathrm{d} S$ are obtainable through crunching the Maxwell relations and using the definitions for $\alpha$, $C_V$ and $\beta_T$),
$$
\mathrm{d} S = \left( \frac{C_V}{T} + \frac{\alpha^2 V}{\beta_T} \right) \mathrm{d} T - \alpha V \mathrm{d} p
$$

So this time around, the situation is much more complicated: using the equation of state we have to express $V$ as a function of *pressure* and *temperature* for this to be a reasonable differential equation. Even in the simplest case, we get
$$
\mathrm{d} S = \left( \frac{C_V (T)}{T} + \frac{\alpha^2 N k_B T}{\beta_T p} \right) \mathrm{d} T - \frac{\alpha N k_B T}{p} \mathrm{d} p
$$

In order for $\mathrm{d} S$ to be exact differential, the following must be true
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \left( \frac{C_V (T)}{T} + \frac{\alpha^2 N k_B T}{\beta_T p} \right) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \frac{\alpha N k_B T}{p}
$$
$$
\frac{\alpha^2 N k_B T}{\beta_T p^2} = \frac{\alpha N k_B}{p}
$$

And we already see this is not possible with constant $\alpha$ and $\beta_T$.

So my question is: what justifies the simple "only $T$ dependance" picture that is usually presented?

Comment: THe relationships involving only temperature must refer to essentially incompressible liquids and solids.

Comment: oh, so then dV = 0?

Comment: Not sure why you're expressing S(T,p) in such a complicated way:  dS = (Cp/T) dT – $\alpha$V dp